# Не работает ArrayAdapter во фрагменте

Tags: android, kotlin

Недавно я начал изучать Kotlin для Android (использую Android Studio).

Взял шаблон проекта, в котором несколько фрагментов, и решил написать код, который выводит список чатов. Но ArrayAdapter (как вы можете видеть) не работает - пишет, что функция не найдена, хотя я импортировал библиотеку. Как это можно исправить?

```
package com.example.teenup.ui.home

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.teenup.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        var chatList = ArrayList<String>()
        chatList.add("Лера")
        chatList.add("Денис")
        chatList.add("Папа")
        chatList.add("Мама")
        chatList.add("Даня")

        val chats: ListView = binding.chats
        chats.adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, chatList)

        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Comment: Не добавляйте код в виде картинки. Добавляйте код в виде текста

Comment: @Pashok, исправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конструктор адаптера первым параметром нужно передать контекст, а не сам фрагмент.

```
chats.adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireСontext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, chatList)
```

Андроид Студио при наведении курсора на ошибку часто дает подсказки, например в этом случае в подсказке она показывает 3 варианта конструктора которыми можно инициализировать адаптер и красным подсвечивает параметры конструктора тип которых не совпадает с требуемым.